Populate fields in classes from an external source instead of application.properties
we can use
@Value("${url}")
private String url;

when we have the property url defined inside application.properties file. How to do this binding of properties to @Value annotation when we don't have an application.properties. We have the properties coming from a server during startup of the app. which is brought like
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("propertiesFile", "config.properties")));

My purpose is to populate the properties like url, username etc coming from external source instead of application.properties

The value annotation actually tries to resolve the placeholder ${url} from Spring's Environment abstraction as said here in the documentation

Property values can be injected directly into your beans by using the @Value annotation, accessed through Spring’s Environment abstraction, or be bound to structured objects through @ConfigurationProperties.

And the Environment does take properties from not only the application property file but also OS environment variables etc. Below link has the full list of property sources spring boot can read from and the order of preference.
Spring boot Externalized configuration
So I would guess that your URL can be read is it is set as a System property too with the same name.

Question was how to setup own property file to Spring.
